# Need advice on laravel modeling (pivot of pivot)

Tags: laravel, database-design, model, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a company auditing system, which is a bit difficult to explain but i will try to keep it simple. Here are the main parts

1. Company
2. Audits (certifications)
3. Clauses (These are questions specific to a certification and they all need to be answered in order for the audit to complete. The user can then add comments, status, mark it as complete etc )

There are lots of audits that a company can be tested for. So a company can have multiple audits. Each audit have some clauses, that needs to be executed in order to complete the audit. A user can also add some data to these clauses, for eg progress of the clause, status, comments etc.

Right now i have these database tables

1. Companies
2. Audits
3. Clauses
4. Companies - Audits  (Pivot table)
5. Clauses - Audit (Pivot table)
6. Companies - Audits - Clauses (pivot of pivot table)

Now the first 5 are pretty standard, but i am not sure how to implement the last one. Right now in companies-audits pivot table i have an auto increment field called companies_audits_id, And i then use this id inside Companies_Audits_Clauses table. In Companies_Audits_Clauses table i also have the fields like status, progress, comments etc.

I am not sure if this is a good idea. So i need your thoughts on it. Every help is appreciated.

**EDIT :**

The company can have many audits, and an audit can also have many companies. Think of audits as certifications, so a company can be certified for different certifications e.g ISO1000, ISO2000 etc. So its necessary to have pivot for audits_companies. Similarly clauses belong to only one certification, in this case ISO2000 might have 10 clauses. And then each company will have certain comments on these clauses.

Comment: Audits don't require a pivot table if audits only have one company.  They just need a `company_id`.  Same with clauses, they should just have an `audit_id`.